# What should I use when cut doesn't cut it?

Tags: command-line, cut

I have a file `cities` like this:

```
[1598] San Diego, US (inactive)
[4517] St Louis, US (inactive)
[6346] Orlando, US (inactive)
```

I want to cut out the city names, so that I have:

```
San Diego
St Louis
Orlando
```

This is the best I could come up with:

```
cut -d ',' -f1 cities | cut -d ']' -f2
```

But that still leaves me with a space before the names. Is there a `cut` like command that I can use that accept delimiters of several characters so I can cut on `]`?

Comment: `tr` is useful for deleting characters you don't want.

Comment: If you try the code in people's answers, you will see three different outputs.  This suggests your question was not 100% clear.  Does "cut out" mean remove or select?  Do you want the `(inactive)` status or not?  Please provide sample output.

Comment: @Mikel - Considering I'm using `cut` to cut things out and you can see the intent of the failed example I have, it should be fairly clear in the context.  I will provide sample out though to clear it up further. :)

Comment: No, not really.  I changed one sentence in your question to "print only the city names", because it was your use of the word "cut" that was unclear to me.  Is my change correct?

Comment: @Mikel - Well we'll just have to disagree then. None of the 3 people that answered before you got it wrong (and you could've looked at them for guidance). :) I don't want to use your word usage because I think it makes the question less interesting to read. With the example output I can't possibly see how anyone would get it wrong. Feel free to downvote if you are unhappy with that though. :)

Comment: @Kit Sunde: With the sample output, it's certainly understandable.  The title is cute.  "cut out" makes me think of what happens when you press Ctrl+X, which is why I suggested the change, but it's your question.  Downvoting would be silly when it's just a simple disagreement.

Comment: Too bad I'm not on a unix machine here but I think in GNU grep there is an option to only show the match, not the entire line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) (also check [Awk Info](http://awk.info/)) is beautiful with that sort of question. Try:

```
awk -F'[],] *' '{print $2}' cities
```

This defines a field separator `-F` as `[],] *` - which means one occurence of either a closing square bracket or a comma, followed by zero or any number of spaces. Of course you can change that to suit any requirement. Read up on regular expressions.

Once the line is split, you can do what you want with the split result. Here, I decided to print out the second field only with `print $2`. Note that it is important to use single quotes around the awk instructions otherwise $2 gets substituted by the shell.

Comment: `]` is not an angle bracket.  Angle brackets are `<>`.  `[]` are "square brackets", or just "brackets".

Comment: I think you need to escape that closing bracket, unless I actually do need to go read up on my regular expressions.

Comment: @cjm - Maybe he's German: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1181243 :)

Comment: @cjm, sorry I meant to say square bracket, typed a little too fast. @Kit, I am not German. You do not want to escape the inner closing bracket (it would serve no purpose), but it must be the first character in the range.

Answer (score 12):

For more complex parsing, you should use [sed(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
sed -e 's/\[[0-9]\+\] \([^,]\+\),.*/\1/' cities
```

Or using `-r` to simplify the regular expression, as suggested by [pepoluan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5589/pepoluan):

```
sed -re 's/\[[0-9]+\] ([^,]+),.*/\1/' cities
```

Comment: +1. you can also use -r to prevent escaping advanced regex chars, greatly simplifying the regex pattern

Answer (score 12):

You can modify the last `cut` in your pipeline to this:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

The above means that field separator is whitespace, and we want to select all fields starting from the second. The complete sequence becomes:

```
cut -d ',' -f1 cities | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

I normally use Perl when things get too hard for sed and grep.

There are a number of ways you could write it in Perl.  For example, you might prefer it to be fast, or you might prefer it to handle slight unexpected problems in the input (e.g. two spaces where one was expected).

One obvious way (assumes id is numeric, city is alphabetic, status is alphabetic):

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^\[\d+\] (\w+(?: \w+)*), \w+ \(\w*\)$/) {
        my $city = $1;
        print "$city\n";
    }
}
```

Or slower but more permissive (does more backtracking):

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^.*\]\s+(.*),.*$/) {
        my $city = $1;
        print "$city\n";
    }
}
```

Or faster (field stops at first occurrence of closing bracket):

```
while (<>) {
    if (/^\[[^]]*\] ([^,]*), \S+ \([^)]*\)$/) {
        my $city = $1;
        print "$city\n";
    }
}
```

From the command line rather than a script, you could use the `-n` option, which basically adds the `while (<>) { BLOCK }` loop:

```
perl -ne '/^\[[^]]*\] ([^,]*), \S+ \([^)]*\)$/ and print $1, "\n";' cities
```

or if you want the usage to resemble cut, you can use the `-F` option, which is similar to awk's `-F` option, for example:

```
perl -a -n -F'/[],]\s+/' -e 'print $F[1], "\n"' cities
```

This way obviously assumes that no field will contain any of the delimiters.